# Error Rails 4 console on staging or production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Join in my office the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s production
```

And I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/production (LoadError)
```

Please, help!!

Comment: Sadly, running `rails s production` doesn't work like `rails c production` does..

Answer (score 7):

Run this command to run the rails server in `production` mode

```
rails s -e production
```

Answer (score 2):

guessing:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s production
```

to:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

Comment: Also can use `env=production rails s`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure this is the problem of your command

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s production
```

change it to:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

usage of `rails s` command is :

```
Usage: rails server [mongrel, thin, etc] [options]

-p, --port=port                  Runs Rails on the specified port.
                                 Default: 3000
-b, --binding=ip                 Binds Rails to the specified ip.
                                 Default: 0.0.0.0
-c, --config=file                Use custom rackup configuration file
-d, --daemon                     Make server run as a Daemon.
-u, --debugger                   Enable ruby-debugging for the server.
-e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment to run this server under (test/development/production).
                                 Default: development
-P, --pid=pid                    Specifies the PID file.
                                 Default: tmp/pids/server.pid
-h, --help                       Show this help message.
```

so the word following `rails s` is expected to be server you want to run your application with i.e. (Thin, WEBrick, FastCGI, CGI, SCGI and LiteSpeed.)

```
rails s thin
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

rails s WEBrick
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Comment: Using `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`, services start,

`-*=> Booting WEBrick*
-*=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http: // localhost: 3000
*=> Run 'rails server -h` for more startup options
*=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
*[22/02/2016 15:00:23] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1
*[22/02/2016 15:00:23] INFO ruby 2.2.2 (13/04/2015) [x86_64-linux]
*[22/02/2016 15:00:23] INFO WEBrick :: HTTPServer # start: pid = 1248 port = 3000`


When I go to my my server I can only see the files in the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

It runs as local, and uses WEBrick 1.3.1 I want to run using apache + passenger + rails

Comment: I think https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04 may help you setup your application.